# SEGFAULT even on the simplest program only when debugging

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, g++

My program is **exactly** this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{

    int a;

    std::cin >> a;
}
```

And it is crashing (SEGFAULT) only when I use the gdb debugger.

I'm compiling with g++.

If it is of any use, this is the disassembler output when the program crashes.

```
->->post-prompt
eax            0x474e5089   1196314761
ecx            0x1  1
edx            0x22fea24    36694564
ebx            0x74ca2fe8   1959407592
esp            0x41afe4c    0x41afe4c
ebp            0x41afe5c    0x41afe5c
esi            0x4e8ffd 5148669
edi            0x0  0
eip            0x74b11a37   0x74b11a37
eflags         0x10202  [ IF RF ]
cs             0x23 35
ss             0x2b 43
ds             0x2b 43
es             0x2b 43
fs             0x53 83
gs             0x2b 43
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** This is the debugger output when invoked via command line:

```
[New Thread 180.0x8e4]
[New Thread 180.0x1a40]
[New Thread 180.0x1bb4]
[New Thread 180.0x19a0]
[New Thread 180.0x1630]
[New Thread 180.0xc28]
[New Thread 180.0x788]
[New Thread 180.0x5f8]

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[Switching to Thread 180.0x5f8]
0x74b11a37 in ?? ()
(gdb) Exception condition detected on fd 0
error detected on stdin
```

Comment: [No repro](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/af0be938691491cb)

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ I'm aware that the code itself is not supposed to crash, nevertheless it does.

Comment: I am not down voting your question because I understand your situation but the problem is somewhere else. *Broken* libraries,... ?

Comment: Bit weird this. Why so many threads? "Error detected on stdin." Could this be gdb and your program scraping it out over your program blocking on stdin? Worth tacking on your compiler and GDB version. OS probably wouldn't hurt, either.

Comment: @user4581301 That's exactly what I was asking myself, even though I do not really understand how threads work. This was happening with QT, so I though it was an issue related to the IDE, but now it's clear that's not the case.
I already reinstalled minGW and it didn't solve the problem yet, maybe the only way out is to reinstall the OS.

Comment: I don't think you want to nuke your OS over this. Which version of mingw are you using, and what's the build command line. What IDE?

Comment: @user4581301
Last time, just to make sure it wasn't anything IDE related, I compiled via command line with g++ and -g flag, also invoked gdb directly via command line.
"Configured with: ../src/gcc-4.9.3/configure --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --host=m
ingw32 --prefix=/mingw --disable-win32-registry --target=mingw32 --with-arch=i58
6 --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,fortran,ada --enable-static --enable-sha
red --enable-threads --with-dwarf2 --disable-sjlj-exceptions --enable-version-sp
ecific-runtime-libs --enable-libstdcxx-debug --with-tune=generic --enable-nls
Thread model: win32"

Comment: No reproduce.  Using g++ version 5.3.0 on Cygwin, Windows 7.  Using gdb version "Cygwin 7.10.1-1".

Comment: Yow! That's a lot of cruft for a simple program like this. Start with `g++ -O0 -g3 <name of input file>`. This should spit out an a.out or a.exe, still not sure which OS you're using, that you can pop into GDB. If you still get an error, there is some sort of low-level configuration screw-up or a conceptual break like trying to debug a cross-compiled win32 program with the default GDB on linux. If no error, start adding more options until you do get the error.

Comment: I'll try! @user4581301 , thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed it!

Turns out that it really was something with windows runtime libraries, so I did a clean reinstall and now everything works just fine!

However I really have no idea of how this came to be.